RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded at Object.hasOwnProperty (<anonymous>) digest: "2107749297" NextJS
Error: Maximum call stack size exceeded NextJS: In this code I want implement the like and unlike functionality to project but in I am countered by this error
This the PostReactions.jsx code
'use client'
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { FaRegComment } from "react-icons/fa";
import { PiShareFatThin } from "react-icons/pi";
import { AiOutlineLike, AiFillLike } from "react-icons/ai";


const PostReactions = ({ postReactions = [], postComments = [], postShares = [] }) => {

  const [user, setUser] = useState('66236aac5820fcac4e235f0c');

  const likesArrIds = [] //postReactions.map((reaction) => reaction.createdBy);
  const [likesArr, setLikesArr] = useState([...likesArrIds]);

  const handleLike = async (userId, postId, isLiked) => {
    const shouldAddLike = {
      postId,
      userId,
      likeType: 'like',
      isReacted: isLiked,
    };

    try {
      const response = await fetch(`/api/like`, {
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(shouldAddLike),
      });
      const parse = await response.json();
      console.log(parse);

      let updatedLikesArr;
      if (!isLiked) {
        updatedLikesArr = likesArr.filter((id) => id !== userId);
      } else {
        updatedLikesArr = [...likesArr, userId];
      }

      setLikesArr(updatedLikesArr);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error occurred while updating like:", error);
    }
  }
  return (
    <div className="w-full md:w-2/3 flex-between py-2 font-poppins ">
      <div className="flex-center space-x-1 md:space-x-2 cursor-pointer" onClick={() => { handleLike(user, '663f2de2d1bbf549ac7fbabe', true) }}>
        <AiFillLike className={`w-5 h-5`} />
        <p className="base-semibold">Liked</p>
      </div>
      {/* <div className="flex-center space-x-1 md:space-x-2 cursor-pointer">
            <AiOutlineLike className={`w-5 h-5`}  />
            <p className="base-semibold">Like</p>
            </div>         */}
      <div className="flex-center space-x-1 md:space-x-2 cursor-pointer">
        <FaRegComment className={`w-5 h-5`} />
        <p className="base-semibold">Comment</p>
      </div>
      <div className="flex-center space-x-1 md:space-x-2 cursor-pointer">
        <PiShareFatThin className={`w-5 h-5`} />
        <p className="base-semibold">Share</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default PostReactions;

I expect the code to execute without encountering the "RangeError" and to identify and resolve the underlying issue causing the error.
After that to implement the like and unlike functionality

The error you face might be caused by the objects you pass to your client component.
According to Next.js documentation:

If you fetch data in a Server Component, you may want to pass data down as props to Client Components. Props passed from the Server to Client Components need to be serializable by React.

This means your props must be plain objects with only key-value pairs without any additional properties or methods that are coming from prototype chains.
